# Cross-Browser/Platform Support for Website

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I designed the website : http://piratesofpopulous.comli.com/
and I am still working on it, But there is a problem, My website doesn't seem to have same design for all browsers, In Chrom and Mozilla, You can see the radius on few things, But In IE its not showing and The layout is totally messed up, Can you tell me how to get it fixed.

My "border-radius and margin" is not showing correctly in IE, Is there anyway to do it in IE?
I haven't define the doc types in PHP and HTML, Can that be a problem?

Also, All of my pages are *****.php format. They have HTML but there extension is .PHP,
So, Do I need to define the doc types and some other border-radius attributes for IE support?

Help please, or My clan members won't join my site.

Comment: Not actually a PHP category question :(

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Having problems with IE is normal and expected. It's the worst browser on the planet. Incompetent at best.

Comment: I was using IE-8 but recently an hour ago changed to IE-9 thinking about the HTML5 & CSS3 support, But still...The border-radius and box-shadow are not working in it, 
But Chrome and Mozilla are displaying it correctly.
I tested the browser here http://html5test.com/ and Chrome got the most points while IE-9 had the least points :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you asked if doctype is important, and the answer is a very big YES.

Add the following line to the very top of your HTML code (above the `<html>` tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should help with the margins and other weird layout problems. Without the doctype, IE goes into "quirks mode", which is a very old mode that works differently to all other browsers.

If you're in IE9, it might also help with the `border-radius` and `box-shadow` problems: IE9 does support these features, but might not support them in quirks mode.

If you're in IE8 or earlier, the browser simply doesn't support `border-radius` or `box-shadow`. My advice is to just let Ie8 users live without these features; your site may not look quite as good, but it'll be usable, and it might encourage them to upgrade their browser.

If you really want to support these features in IE8, there is a script called [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) that adds both `border-radius` and `box-shadow` features to IE. Click the link to download it and follow the instructions for setting it up on your site. Whether it's worth the effort to make IE8 look good is up to you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was using IE-8 but I changed to IE-9, I added the <!DOCTYPE html>
In index.php but still now working, border-radius and box-shadow are not working, In mozilla and Chrome Its okay

Comment: hopefully it has solved the margin and other layout problems though? You should also check that your IE is in IE9 mode, not IE8-compatibility mode (or even IE7-compatibility mode). box-shadow and border-radius work in IE9, but not in those modes. You'd need the CSS3Pie hack for that, same as with a real copy of IE8 or IE7. (you can check and change the mode in IE's Developer Tools window; press F12 to see it)

Comment: Okay, But If my clients visit that page, They shouldn't be needing that all stuff,Do they?

Comment: CSS3Pie is a script that you add to the site. It's basically just another Javascript file (it works a bit different to most JS, but that's all it is). So no, your users don't need to do anything special; it's you that adds it to the site, not your users.

Comment: Oh,I thought its a plugin like firebug, Where can I get it?

Comment: see the link in the answer -- http://css3pie.com/ Full instructions and examples on that site.

Answer (score -1):

I think part of your problem is that you are missing stuff like this in your css to support the browser clans.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
```